# How to check if an item exists in the checkboxlist before adding an item to the checkboxlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkboxlist and i am getting duplicate list items in the checkboxlist. I want to check if the particular item is exist in the checkboxlist before add an item. what is the optimized way to do this check?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkboxlist"  CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" />

   chkboxlist.Items.Add("GEORGIA");
   chkboxlist.Items.Add("OHIO");
```

Before adding any state to the checkbox list , i want to check the state value is already exist in the checbox list. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FindByValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx) property for check if a value exists. If value not exists the method return null.

By code

```
If(checkboxlist.Items.FindByValue("yourvalue") !=null)
    {
         // Exists
    }
```

Comment: I know this is old, if it's not `null` how do I select that checkbox? Thanks.

Comment: You can set the Selected property to true. A thing like this checkboxlist.Items.FindByValue("yourvalue").Selected=true; Or better var item=checkboxlist.Items.FindByValue("yourvalue"); Item.Selected=true;

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's `Enumerable.Any` like

```
string newItem = "OHIO";
if (chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(r => r.Text == newItem))
{
    //Already exists
}
else
{
    chkboxlist.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```

If you want case insensitive comparison then you can do:

```
if (chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
      .Any(r => String.Equals(r.Text,newItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just need to add new item section. So i have tried something like below 

string newItem = "OHIO";
if (chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(r => r.Text != newItem))
{
chkboxlist.Items.Add(newItem);
}

Comment: nope. you are code is good. I wanted to check just if there is no value like "Ohio" , just go and add the item. So i am not sure where in your code to check for !=null option.

Comment: @Selva, just invert the condition like `if (!chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(r => string.Equals(r.Text,newItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))` or `if (!chkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(r => r.Text == newItem))` notice the `!` in the start of condition inside if statement

Comment: Thank you so much. do we have any single line code to delete all items in a checkboxlist via C#?

Comment: @Selva, `chkboxlist.Items.Clear();`